# How to add colorscale to bar graph in dash python

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am plotting a bar graph that updates every second I want to add colorscale to it.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

@app.callback(Output('my-graph', 'figure'),
              [Input('my-interval-component', 'n_intervals')])
def update_graph_soc(n):
    connection = sqlite3.connect(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\database\newbase.db', )
    connection.execute('pragma journal_mode=wal')
    data = connection.cursor()
    latest = None
    try:
        data = connection.cursor()
        latest = (data.execute("""SELECT
                                    v1,v2,v3,v4
                                    SNO FROM sop where SNO ==(SELECT MAX([SNO]) FROM [sop])""").fetchall().__getitem__(0))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    z = []
    values = go.Bar(
        x=['v1','v2','v3','v4'], y=latest)
    return {'data': [values], 'layout': go.Layout(title='graph',yaxis_title='values(in x)',
                                                  xaxis_title='sample: ' + str(int(latest[4])),colorscale='Viridis')}
```

I was trying to do it in the above way where I was giving Viridis as colorscale but it is not working. Any help will be appreciated Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@eliasdabbas` answered this in the [Plotly Community Forum](https://community.plotly.com/t/colorscale-in-bar-chart/15509): you need to pass `colorscale` to the `marker` parameter dictionary instead of the `layout`:

```
values = go.Bar(
    x=['v1','v2','v3','v4'], 
    y=latest, 
    marker={'color': [i+1 for i,_ in enumerate(y)], 'colorscale': 'Viridis'}
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the proposed edit @xhlulu! I know that `go.Bar` is the convention but was trying to match OP's syntax - next time I'll submit such edits myself. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I have a problem with this approach, all the bars in the bar graph have the same color could you help me out with this?

Comment: marker = {
        "color" : [1,2,3,4],
        "colorscale" : 'Viridis',
    }

Comment: I did it in the above way and it worked is there any other way to do it where I don't need to supply the [1,2,3,4] in the marker.

Comment: You can make it more generalizable with `marker = { "color" : [i+1 for i,_ in enumerate(y)], "colorscale" : 'Viridis'}`